# Convergence of a series with a parameter $a>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hello I have this exercise:
Please help me determine what values ​​of $a > 0$ the series below converges:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{a n+2}{3n+1}\right)^{n}$$

Comment: We need your input on the problem. Where are your stuck? What have you done so far?

Comment: This is not a power series stricto sensu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

When $a=3$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{3 n+2}{3n+1}\right)^{n}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac1{3n+1}\right)^{n}
=\sum_{m=4,\text{ step }3}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac1m\right)^{(m-1)/3}\\
=\sum_{m=4,\text{ step }3}^{\infty}{\frac{\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\frac1m\right)^m}}{\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1m}}}.$$

The expression of the numerator should ring a bell.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, whenever you have an entire expression raised to the $n^\text{th}$ power, first try using the $n$-th Root Test. As a reminder, the $n$-th Root Test states the following:

Let $r = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_n)^{1/n}$. Then three possibilities exist:

- $r < 1 \implies $ the series converges
- $r = 1 \implies $ inconclusive, requires further consideration
- $r > 1 \implies $ the series diverges

This is not the entire answer, but I will say that, if you use this Root Test, each of the three cases above will give you a range of values that $a$ is allowed to be. If you need further hints, just ask. (In the future, though, be sure to state what you're stuck on; vague questions usually elicit vague--or no--answers.)

Good luck!!